# Scaling of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Lets say you have two column vectors:
$$\begin{array}{|r r|}
 3 & -4 \\
 4 &  3 \\
\end{array}$$

How to find the scaling of this matrix? I thought that it can be any number but apparently it is $5$ which helps to find the rotational angle for this matrix with
$$\begin{array}{|r r|}
 \cos & -\sin \\
 \sin &  \cos \\
\end{array}$$

For this example the angle would be $\arccos(0.6)$ counterclockwise?
Why is the scaling $5$? Why not $4$ or $3$ or $2$?

Comment: What is the scaling of a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see this would be to see how the matrix affects the vectors $[1\; 0]$ and $[0\; 1]$. For instance, if we call your matrix $A$, then we see that
$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3\\4\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -4\\3\end{pmatrix}.$$
How did these lengths change? We took $[1\; 0]$, a vector of length $1$, and $A$ output a vector of length $5$. Similarly, $[0\; 1]$ yielded another vector of length $5$.

Since every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a unique sum of $[1\; 0]$ and $[0\; 1]$, each of which is scaled by a factor of $5$, and as $A$ is linear, we must have that $A$ scales every vector by length $5$. Thus $A$ is of the form
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 5&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix} O$$
where $O$ is some orthogonal matrix (a rotation/reflection matrix in this case). $\diamondsuit$

I didn't use hint you were given because it's unnecessary. But you could in principle first find the rotation matrix (i.e. the matrix I called $O$ above), and then invert it to find the scaling factor.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We scale the vectors by $5$ because we want them to have length $1$. If the coordinates of the vector are $a$ and $b$, we wish to scale the vector by $c>0$ such that $\sqrt{(ca)^2+(cb)^2}=1$ (this is the length of the vector). In the first case we have $a=3$ and $b=4$ for the first vector, so the equation becomes $\sqrt{16c^2+9c^2}=1\implies 5c=1\implies c=\dfrac{1}{5}$. The second case is the same.

Comment: Ok now I understand it. Thank you